# Correct indentation for wrapped lines

Tags: indentation

I have the following wrapped text, especially when you use a lot of windows:

[image: Wrapped lines in Emacs]

I'm wondering if the indentation of wrapped text could be changed like in Vim:

[image: Indentation of wrapped lines in Vim]

When figuring out, it seems the [AutoFillMode](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoFillMode) is responsible for this. I was hoping this might be improved in Emacs 25. After upgraded to a compiled binary of Emacs 25, I see the same behaviour.

So I'm wondering if I could solve this in an another way?

Comment: Perhaps the solution could take advantage of the `wrap-prefix`:   http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Truncation.html#Truncation  See also `wrap-prefix` property:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Properties.html

Comment: Check out the `adaptive-wrap` package.

Comment: You both are right, lawlist and kaushalmodi. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>package-install</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>adaptive-wrap</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>:

```el
(setq-default adaptive-wrap-extra-indent 2)
(add-hook 'visual-line-mode-hook #'adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode)
(global-visual-line-mode +1)
```

Comment: `adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode` is not a global mode by default. But you can [make it global](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/2015b51b2e0129e0af0d0efbb716b18f38038524/setup-files/setup-visual.el#L202-L218) if you like and not tie it with the activation of `visual-line-mode`.

Comment: Surprising to see how easily this could be achieved. Why is this not included in the default package of Emacs?

Comment: The package itself is in ELPA, so that could be fairly easily arranged, at least from a legal standpoint. I'd much rather have Tetris be the external package and adaptive-wrap be built-in but such is life.

Comment: @kaushalmodi does `adaptive-wrap` make sense without `visual-line-mode`?

Comment: @PythonNut No it doesn't. `visual-line-mode` should be enabled for `adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode` to work. I use a slightly different approach than yours.. I just enable `adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode` globally. That's not recommended by the package author Stefan Monnier (based on personal email communication) as it costs non-negligible resources to enable this mode globally. But that hasn't affected my use cases.

Comment: @PythonNut On further thought, I might start doing just what you do.. enable `adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode` using the `visual-line-mode-hook` :)

Comment: @PythonNut [Here's my updated config](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/c6e69f0c353d8e538c0810f60d22d0c88cc665ba/setup-files/setup-visual.el#L320-L357): I don't enable `visual-line-mode` globally. But now I enable `adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode` only when the former is enabled. Thanks for that nudge.

Comment: @kaushalmodi yep. Thanks for the sanity check. :)

Comment: @PythonNut Note that `setq` won't work for `adaptive-wrap-extra-indent` as that's a buffer local var. You need to use `setq-default` instead.

Comment: @kaushalmodi Thanks for the tip. I fixed this [in my config](https://github.com/PythonNut/emacs-config/commit/ccdf3ca) a while ago (idk, there's some other stuff in that commit too :|), but I haven't updated my answer. Should be updated now.

Comment: I'd suggest putting the `require' of things like `adaptive-wrap' and `diminish' in the hook function, unless those libraries are needed for the rest of the code you load.

Comment: First things first: really adaptive-wrap rather than Tetris?  Are you nuts?  Second: Stephen Berman is the author, not me.  Third: why in `with-eval-after-load` whereas it should work both before and after loading (and you've loaded it just above anyway)?  Finally: I'd remove the `dimish` business from your example, since it's not directly related.

Comment: @Stefan I actually have no idea what you mean by "Tetris".

Comment: @PythonNut: For reference: `...I'd much rather have Tetris be the external package... – PythonNut Aug 8 '15 at 19:56`