# Loading adaptive wrap as default

Tags: init-file, line-break, wrapping

I've been using emacs for a long time but still have little understanding of elisp; I basically copy code I find on websites into my `.emacs` until it seems to do what I want.

I only recently discovered `global-visual-line-mode` (I had been using `auto-fill`), and now see based on [this other answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14589/correct-indentation-for-wrapped-lines) and [this one at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559061/emacs-how-to-keep-the-indentation-level-of-a-very-long-wrapped-line) that I also want `adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode`. It works great when I turn it on manually, but when I blindly add the code provided in the former answer to my `.emacs`, I get

```
File error: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, adaptive-wrap
```

while blindly adding the code from the latter answer loads fine, but does not actually succeed in turning on `adaptive-wrap-mode`. I've played with variations and I'm sure the solution is simple, but I just don't see it. How do I just get it to turn on both `global-visual-line-mode` *and* `adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode` by default?

I would be happy if I could get them both running just for my markdown files.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add

```
(package-initialize t)
```

at the beginning of your `~/emacs`.  IIRC Emacs-25 will tend to do that for you, but it's even better to do it manually.

The problem is simply that `adaptive-wrap-mode` is not defined until the ELPA packages have been initialized.  If your `~/.emacs` file doesn't initialize the ELPA packages with `package-initialize`, Emacs does it for you, but it can only notice it after your `~/.emacs` is loaded, so the functions defined by the ELPA packages won't be available until after your `~/.emacs` is loaded.

Comment: Three comments: (a) Wow that worked! I love StackExchange! Thank you! (b) is there any reason not to use `(add-hook 'visual-line-mode-hook 'adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode)` instead of the fancy code those other two answers have? (c) I never would have guessed this - ELPA is also new to me (but handy). I feel like just as I'm learning how to run some part of emacs it changes on me, sometimes ...