# Org-Mode correct indentation

Tags: spacemacs, indentation

I am using spacemacs and try to use full text indentation. When I execute "visual-line-mode" and "adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode" by hand via M-x the text will indent, when I edit it. Of course I tried to automate this behaviour with the following configuration:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'org
   (setq org-startup-indented t) ; Enable `org-indent-mode' by default
   (add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'visual-line-mode)
   (add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode))
```

But this won't work.. and I have no idea why. I also have tried several other solutions (like this one: [Correct indentation for wrapped lines](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14589/correct-indentation-for-wrapped-lines)), but nothing worked for me.

Here a screenshot of my emacs setup after launch: [image: Image after launch]

And here is my emacs after I manually entered the above commands: [image]

Can someone help me with my problem or is there another solution for that problem?

Comment: Maybe it is related to this? https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/1418

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following configurations to the org layer did the trick for me

```
 (org :variables
      org-startup-indented t
      org-indent-mode t)
```