# Use adaptive wrapping only in one specific major mode

Tags: wrapping

I am using adaptive wrapping (see [Correct indentation for wrapped lines](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14589/correct-indentation-for-wrapped-lines)) but it applies to all major modes. I would like to only use it for html. What I have tried so far is adding the following to my .emacs file:

```
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook 
           ;;(setq-default adaptive-wrap-extra-indent 2)
           (add-hook 'visual-line-mode-hook #'adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode)
           (global-visual-line-mode +1)
           ;;(setq adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode t)
           )
```

This does not work since the adaptive line wrap is still active in all major modes. How should I change the snippet to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're trying to do is:

```
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook 'adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode)
```

That is, add `adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode` directly to the `html-mode` hook. Adding it to `visual-line-mode-hook` will make it active whenever `visual-line-mode` is enabled, and you've enabled that globally with `(global-visual-line-mode 1)`.

Resorting to `advice-add` may appear to work, but it's a round-about way to do it, and the results might not be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

The arguments of `add-hook` are `HOOK`, `FUNCTION`, `APPEND`, and `LOCAL` (see quote of the docstring for `add-hook` below).

The 1st arg in your code is `'html-mode-hook` which is fine.

The 2nd is `(add-hook 'visual-line-mode-hook #'adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode)` which is not good.
It is a form that is evaluated and its return value is used as argument to `add-hook`.
Effectively `(add-hook 'visual-line-mode-hook #'adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode)` is run where you wanted to run `(add-hook 'html-mode ...)`.

The third arg is `(global-visual-line-mode +1)`. It is also run where you wanted to run `(add-hook 'html-mode ...)`.
The help of function `global-visual-line-mode` does not specify a return value. Therefore the return value is open to the developer. It is a general **no-go** to use that return value if you are not the developer.

You should put the stuff from `add-hook` in your code into a function, say `my-html-mode-hook-fun` and hook `my-html-mode-hook-fun` to `html-mode-hook`.

Furthermore, it does not make sense to put `(global-visual-line-mode)` into `html-mode-hook`. I replaced it by `(visual-line-mode)`.

```el
(defun my-html-mode-hook-fun ()
  "I want to have fun in `html-mode-hook';-)."
  (add-hook 'visual-line-mode-hook #'adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode nil 'buffer-local)
  (visual-line-mode)
  ;; further nice stuff you want to do after (de-)activating html-mode
)

(add-hook 'html-mode-hook #'my-html-mode-hook-fun)
```

Some folks use a `lambda` instead of a named function.
I do very much prefer named functions:

1. It is easier to instrument named functions for debugging.
2. The named function can easily be modified and redefined.
3. They can easily be removed from the hook:

   ```el
   (setq html-mode-hook (cl-remove 'my-html-mode-hook-fun html-mode-hook))
   ```

Quote of the docstring of `add-hook`:

> `add-hook` is a compiled Lisp function in `subr.el`.
>
> `(add-hook HOOK FUNCTION &optional APPEND LOCAL)`
>
> For more information check the manuals.
>
> Add to the value of `HOOK` the function `FUNCTION`.
>   `FUNCTION` is not added if already present.
>   `FUNCTION` is added (if necessary) at the beginning of the hook list
>   unless the optional argument `APPEND` is non-nil, in which case
>   `FUNCTION` is added at the end.
>
> The optional fourth argument, `LOCAL`, if non-nil, says to modify
>   the hook’s buffer-local value rather than its global value.
>   This makes the hook buffer-local, and it makes t a member of the
>   buffer-local value.  That acts as a flag to run the hook
>   functions of the global value as well as in the local value.
>
> `HOOK` should be a symbol, and `FUNCTION` may be any valid function.  If
>   `HOOK` is void, it is first set to nil.  If `HOOK`’s value is a single
>   function, it is changed to a list of functions.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following code to my .emacs eventually worked for me:

```
(defun myAdWrap ()
  (add-hook 'visual-line-mode-hook #'adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode)
  (global-visual-line-mode +1))
(advice-add 'html-mode :before #'myAdWrap)
```